# Error in R when creating new column based on the difference of 2 other columns

Tags: r

Keep getting error, on what should be simple code. Tried multiple ways per other questions/answers on here.

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, speed_diff, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 260
```

I have a pretty simple data table. I have 2 columns (stall_speed and airspeed) I am simply trying to subtract the airspeed from the stall speed to get the difference.

I omitted NAs, made sure both columns were numeric and rounded to the same decimal place, I tried creating the new column first with all 0's (after getting the error when trying to just use "flights2$speed_diff <- flights2$airspeed - flights2$stallspeed"),  also tried taking the absolute value of the difference, still got error. Not sure what else to try.

code I last used:

```
flights <- na.omit(flights)
flights <- flights %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits = 2)

flights2 <- flights
flights2[1:125] <- list(NULL)

flights2$alpha_after <- flights$P36..Alpha.Floor.after
flights2$stall_speed <- flights$P36..Stall.Speed.At.Time.of
flights2$airspeed <- flights$P36..Airspeed.At.Time.of
flights2$minspeed <-flights$P36..Min.Airspeed.Recorded.During.
flights2$airspeed <- as.numeric(flights2$airspeed)
flights2$stall_speed <- as.numeric(flights2$stall_speed)
flights2$speed_diff <- 000.00
flights2$speed_diff <- as.numeric(flights2$stall_speed)
flights2$speed_diff <- flights2$airspeed - flights2$stallspeed
```

expected it to subtract stall_speed from airspeed. instead it gave me an error.

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, speed_diff, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 260
```

Comment: Confusion about `stallspeed` and `stall_speed`? `flights2$speed_diff <- flights2$airspeed - flights2$stall_speed` should work. `flights2$stallspeed` doesn't exist and is therefore `NULL`, which give a length of 0.

Comment: Hi Ashley, if you can make this a minimum reproducible example (use `dput` to give us your data frame, and make sure we can cut and paste your code to get the same error you got) probably will have more luck for people to help. Thanks :)

Comment: i fixed the error. thank you for assistances.